# Accessing WebView login page with a certificate in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, ssl, identityserver4, maui

I am trying to access the host's login page, through an android application on MAUI with WebView. However, if I use **HTTP**, the web page is displayed fine on the emulator. But due to IdentityServer restrictions for **HTTPS** I am not able to log in. If I use HTTPS in my URL the blanc page is displayed on the emulator and in an Output, I get this error:

```
[cr_X509Util] Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
[chromium] [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

How can I access that login page using the **HTTPS** in URL ?

View:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <WebView x:Name="webAuth" 
            Source="{Binding AuthUrl, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"     
                 />
     
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel:

```
   private UrlWebViewSource authUrl;
        public UrlWebViewSource AuthUrl
        {
            get { return authUrl; }
            set { SetProperty(ref authUrl, value); }
        }

        private UrlWebViewSource CreateAuthUrl()
        {
            var result = new UrlWebViewSource();            
            result.Url = "https://10.0.2.2:7187/prijava?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dfrontend%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8090%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid";
            return result;

        }
```

MainActivity.cs :

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        #if DEBUG
            HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = GetInsecureHandler();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(insecureHandler);
        #else
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        #endif        
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                return true;
            return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
        };
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I have tried to add that GetInsecureHandler in my MainActivity.cs, I have also tried to add self-signed certificate with PM dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Answer (score 1):

A .NET MAUI app running in the Android emulator can consume an ASP.NET Core web service that's running locally over HTTPS. The process to enable this is as follows:

1. Trust the self-signed development certificate on your machine.
2. Specify the address of your local machine.
3. Bypass the local development certificate security check.

For more details, you can refer to the following doc:
[Connect to local web services from Android emulators and iOS simulators | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services)